# VC Dimension with rectangles with horizontal and vertical edges

Tags: computer-science, machine-learning

I posted this question in stack overflow but no one answer it so I moved it to math overflow...

---

I am learning theory of machine learning and have some confusion about VC dimensions. According to the text book, the VC dimension of 2D axis-aligned rectangles is 4 which means it cannot shatter 5 points.

I found an example here: [Cornell](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs683/2008sp/lecture%20notes/683notes_0428.pdf)
[image: Sample]

However I still cannot understand this example. What if we use a rectangle like this (the red one)

[image: Another]

Then we can classify this point out of them. Why is this incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "shatter" a 5-point set means to produce all 32 possible subsets (by using a rectangle in each case). In this example, you cannot produce a subset that contains just the four black points without containing the red one.

Comment: Do you mean that shatter doesn't mean simply split positive and negative points but have to contain all positive points in that hypothesis?

Comment: You are given a set $S$ of 5 points. The points do not have signs. $S$ has 32 different subsets. For each subset $T$ of $S$, you have to find an axis-parallel rectangle that contains all the points of $T$ and doesn't contain any point of $S\setminus T$. But this is impossible